# Large text in tab is not showing completely Flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs, flutter-layout, tabbar

I am working on a Flutter project that requires tabs, but one of the tab name is large, the name is not showing completely, as demonstrated in picture, How can I resolve this issue, I want the `TabBar` text to be `multiline`, I am new to Flutter so any help will be appreciated.

[Current tab situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubw1w.png)

Here is the code

```
TabBar(
  tabs: [
    Tab(
      text: "Clock",
      icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
    ),
    Tab(
      text: "Alarm",
      icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
    ),
    Tab(
      text: "Stopwatch",
      icon: Icon(Icons.av_timer),
    ),
    Tab(
      text: "Countdown Timer",
      icon: Icon(Icons.timer_rounded),
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: show the code a little bit. you can use \n for next line.

Comment: Text(
maxlines:2

Comment: As only one letter is hidden, you can decrease the font size

Comment: @Mahi I am not using Text widget, secondly after `\n` the text allignment does not remain centered

Comment: okay. whatever it is.. you have solved it. good.

Comment: Thank You very much, Your comment did gave me the Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, instead of using `text` attribute I used

```
child: Text(
  "Countdown Timer",
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

Adding `textAlign` to it solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

Add `labelPadding` or make the tabs scrollable using `isScrollable`

```
TabBar(
  isScrollable: true,
  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
  tabs: [
Tab(
  text: "Clock",
  icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
),
Tab(
  text: "Alarm",
  icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
),
Tab(
  text: "Stopwatch",
  icon: Icon(Icons.av_timer),
),
Tab(
  text: "Countdown Timer",
  icon: Icon(Icons.timer_rounded),
)
],),
```

Comment: This should be the accepted anwser. 
Can you add the use of  tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start to avoid wierd spaces at the start of the tabs?

Answer (score 3):

put Tab Text into Expanded widget

```
child:Expaned(
child : Text(
  "Countdown Timer",
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
)),
```